# Does $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} =\frac{1}{xn}$ conveges pointwise to $0$ but does not convege $L_{1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Im trying to find an example of a sequence of  continuous functions in $[0,1]$ that converges pointwise to $0$ but does not converge in $L_1$.

So i came up with this  $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} =\frac{1}{xn}$ , I think that $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$ converges to $0$ because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{xn}=0$

but I am having hard time to prove that it does not converge in $L_1$, this is my attempt  : 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\left|f_{n}\right|\right|_{1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits _{0}^{1}\frac{1}{xn}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int\limits _{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]_{0}^{1}$

and $\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]_{0}^{1} = \infty$ but on the otheside I have $\frac{1}{n}$ that goes to $0$. Is this even a valid example ?

**Edit** : Ok so my example is not even defined in the domain, something like this sequence of functions in the picture that almost everywhere is 0 but in one point goes crazy should be the right way to think of ?

[image]

**Edit #2** : I think $f_{n}\left(x\right)=ne^{-nx}$ will be good because in $[0,1]$ the integral converges to $1$ but the function is pointwise $0$.

Comment: Your sequence of functions is not in $L_1[0,1]$.

Comment: $f_n(x):=\frac{1}{xn}$ is not defined in zero, so it's not a function defined on $[0,1]$.

Comment: To answer your edit: If you consider a continuous function on a compact domain, it has to be bounded above and below. In particular the craziness of the function is heavily limited and the integral is finite.

Comment: But try to make a sequence of functions that in one point becomes higher and higher such that the "peak" around becomes narrower, you can do this in such a way that the functions converge pointwise to zero but the integral stays the same non-zero number throughout.

Comment: I wasnt so clear in my question, The sequence just should not converges to $0$ in $L_1$ so if it will keep the integral constant for every $n$ that will be good.Does Dirichlet kernel would work ? it goes negative and positive so im not sure

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if you want pointwise convergence in *every* point you need a moving spike, narrower for greater $n$. For the $\not\to L^1$ you need a taller spike for greater $n$.

Comment: something like $n\cdot e^{-nx}$ will be good ?

Comment: @limitless, your example is good if pointwise convergence a.e. is enough.

Comment: Why it isnt pointwise convergence? isnt $\lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{-nx}=0$ for every $x\in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: @limitless, $f_n(0) = n$.